# How do I solve INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY for running an Android Things app out of the box?

Tags: android, android-things

I'm trying to follow *Android Developers*' [guide here](https://developer.android.com/things/training/first-device/create-studio-project) on making an *Android Things* project, but I'm totally stuck on how to get it to run.

I'm trying to run it on a physical *Pixel 3* device via *ADB* and I keep getting `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` when it tries to start. I'm just trying to get the default *"Hello World"* app to work.

I'm not sure what steps I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to run it on a physical PIxel 3.

You can't. Only the following [two hardwares are supported by Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms).